# What does Ksplice actually do?

Tags: kernel

So I installed Ksplice on Ubuntu 10.04:

```
# download the installer
wget https://www.ksplice.com/uptrack/dist/lucid/ksplice-uptrack.deb
dpkg -i ksplice-uptrack.deb

# install dependencies
apt-get install -f

# set auto-updates
vi /etc/uptrack/uptrack.conf
autoinstall = yes
```

and...?

**Question**: This means that if there is a minor/major Kernel update, then Ksplice could install it without asking, and I **really** don't need to reboot my computer anymore? (until 2013-04 according to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#Releases)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ksplice allows you to apply patches to a running kernel without rebooting the system.

It freezes your kernel execution momentarily and points the routines that are modified to the new "patched" routines.  Once this has been re-pointed, it resumes your kernel execution.

Most /minor/ updates would probably be patched in this method but any significant changes would still require a reboot.  Since most security patches are considered minor adjustments, this would work.  Major updates would require a reboot regardless.